# I need to search for words or phrases in text against a database

Tags: php, mysqli

I am having a problem when some words are all uppercase and others are not. I need to find words or phrases even if they are in uppercase or not.

Here is my code:

```
 $a = "I  have a FREE offer of leads for you and you need to CLICK HERE right now before this FREE opportunity passes you by. You can make money right away. visit our website right now and don't pass on this!";

 $result = mysqli_query($res, "SELECT sword FROM words"); 
 $myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

 while ($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$sword = strtolower($myrow['sword']);
 if (preg_match("/$sword/", $a)) {
echo "Found $myrow[sword]!<br /><br />";
 }

 }
```

I have a list of words and phrases in a database. It finds the words opportunity, make money, leads. But it will not find FREE offer, FREE opportunity, CLICK HERE even though I have free offer, free opportunity, click here in the database all lowercase.

What can I do to be sure it will find those phrases and words no matter if they are all caps, some caps or all lowercase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the code you have actually fetches database results and loops and essentially does what you want except for the case sensitivity issue, you could just change the preg_match statement and add an /i flag to make it case-insensitive:

```
if (preg_match("/$sword/i", $a)) { // note the lowercase "i" after the slash
    echo "Found $myrow[sword]!<br /><br />";
 }
```

You should, as a matter of course, **always** check the result of database actions for errors. mysqli_query returns **FALSE** if something goes wrong

```
$result = mysqli_query($res, "SELECT sword FROM words");
if (!$result) {
    die("something went wrong with the query");
}
```